# Diode laser optics - How to shape the beam of a Diode bar?

Tags: optics, laser, design

I have a 40w, 808nm, CS mount diode bar. I would like to build a something similar to a Rofin Dilas laser diode. How to choose the optics, measure distance, focus the beam into a fiber coupler?

I came across the following book "Laser Beam Shaping: Theory and Techniques, Second Edition
edited by Fred M. Dickey" - Will it be a good start to learn?

Comment: How much laser optics experience do you have? Do you have a supervisor that can guide you?

Comment: Note that this is an IR laser (so not visible to many people - some may see it though) class 3B or 4 laser. Discuss with you local laser safety officer to determine required PPE and other hazard mitigation.

Comment: @JoséAndrade Not much, I attended a course of Optics and Photonics back in 2021. I do not have a supervisor that can guide me.

Comment: I second Jon Custer's comment and I would imagine that such a project would be extremely hard without any guidance. I can imagine that for someone - with no prior laser and optics hands-on experience while supervised - would probably take between one and two years to complete such a project with proper results and robustness, which is paramount to avoid any accidents. Time would be needed to understand the concepts, to experiment, to wait for components etc.

Answer (score 1):

This highly depends on the geometry of your setup and the beam profile you want to achieve.
If you are somewhat relaxed about the beam profile, a convex lens with high numerical aperture is enough. After some propagation distance, focus the beam in a single mode fiber. You loose some light power, but end up with a somewhat clean gaussian profile.
The power losses due to the mode cleaning usually amount to 30-40%. You might need some endcaps to protect the fiber.